# Alert before hard deleting mailbox in MS Exchange

Tags: office365, exchange-2016

I would like to know how to set alert before mailbox would be hard deleted after remove exchange license, for example as email to certain address.

Answer (score 0):

This need doesn't seem feasible.

According to my research, there is no such function in exchange.

In addition, you may need some additional scripts to do this, but the Exchange server cannot use the script.